# Is the spectrum of a "self adjoint" operator real on $\ell^p$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

There might be an obvious answer to the question, but it doesn't come to mind.

Suppose we have an infinite matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, which defines a bounded linear operator on $\ell^p$, i.e. for all sequences $(x_i)\in \ell^p, p>1$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty\big|\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j\Big|^p \leq C \Vert x \Vert_{p}^p.$$
For some positive constant $C$.
Furthermore, assume that $a_{ij}=\overline{a_{ji}}$. Is it true that the spectrum of $A$ on $\ell^p $ is real ?

Comment: Do you know whether the point spectrum is always real?

Comment: Yes, Jochen, because the hypothesis implies that $A$ also is bounded on $\ell_q$, $1/p+1/q=1$, hence all eigenvectors are in $\ell_2$. Basically the same argument gives a positive answer to the OP's question (I think).

Comment: @BillJohnson Your argument doesn't seem to use the fact $p>1$; but there are known examples of "self-adjoint" (i.e. conjugate symmetric) convolution operators on $l^1$(free group) whose spectrum has non-empty interior

Comment: Comment for the OP: I suspect the answer is negative for suitable convolution operators on $\ell^p({\bf F}_2)$ but right now I don't remember if the details for the $p=1$ case work for $1<p<2$.

Comment: Actually, it may be enough to work on ${\bf FS}_2$, the free monoid generated by 2 elements: for $p=1$ the construction in the proof of Theorem 5.1 of Jenkins's 1970 paper https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102977529 but as I said, I have not tried to see if the same ideas wor for $1<p<2$.

Comment: There are self-adjoint operators in $L^2$, generating (analytic) semigroups in $L^p$ for all $p$, such that the spectrum is not real for $p \neq 2$. One can take $L=r^2D_{rr}+2rD_r$ in the half-line. The spectrum is a parabola which degenerates into the negative half-line when $p=2$. The resolvents and the semigroups have similar bad properties, by the spectral mapping theorem. Maybe a discrete version can be contructed using them.

Comment: I think I remember there is a paper by Gohberg and Krupnik in which they construct an operator on $\ell_p$ which is self-adjoint for $p=2$ and the spectrum is an ellipsoid por $p\neq 2$ which increases with $p>2$.  Unfortunately, I have no access to my office.

Comment: @M. Gonzalez Very nice If you can recover that example (or give a more precise reference). I am also locked at home but I have online access to the library.

Comment: I guess the only correct part of my comment above is that the point spectrum is real when $p<2$ (because the operator is bounded on $\ell_2$ and $\ell_p \subset \ell_2$).

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune It is something I used in my Thesis, around 1983. I have tried to find the reference, but I failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that I have found a counter example myself.

For the Hilbert matrix 
$$ H_\lambda:= \big( \frac{1}{1-\lambda+k+n} \big)_{k,n\geq 0}, \lambda < 1 $$
Rosenblum in "On the Hilbert Matrix I, Proceedings of the AMS" proves that the pointspectrum  considered as an operator on $\ell^p, p>2$ contains the set 
$$ \{ \pi \sec(\pi u ) : | \Re ( u )| < 1/2-1/p \}. $$

If one could provide a more elementary counterexample I would be interested in looking at.

Comment: However, I think it is true for $1 < p \le 2$ because, for $q \ge p$, if we denote $\sigma^q(A)$ the spectrum of the unbounded operator $A$ on $\ell^q$ with domain $\{x \in \ell^q \mid Ax \in \ell^q\}$ then we can show that the spectrum is increasing with $q$ meaning that $\sigma^q(A) \subset \sigma^r(A)$ for $p \le q \le r$. If I am not mistaken, for $1 < p \le 2$, the operator $A$ induce a self-adjoint operator on $\ell^2$ so $\sigma^p(A) \subset \sigma^2(A) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you can provide the missing details please go ahead and post it as an answer, I will accept it.